# Spring boot liquibase add two 2 reference url paths

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I was trying to integrate liquibase with spring boot where i am trying to generate diff between Entities and database tables. As per document one should define:

referenceUrl property in liquibase.properties file, which will tell the Entities directory path and the url property which will tell the database location.

I am able to generate diff with `mvn liquibase:diff` for one Entity path.

Problem is i have two Entities directory paths, how can i include two paths in referenceUrl which will take diff between entities defined in these 2 paths with database url.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I got the solution, one can add comma separated paths in referenceUrl

```
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.****.***.bot.model, com.****.***.autofaq.model
```

models are present under 2 packages

> com.****.***.bot.model, com.****.***.autofaq.model